# Problem with finding the first occurence of an element of a multi-dimensional array in JavaScript with maybe an incorrect understanding of Splice()

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, jasmine

To start off, I'm a beginner to coding and I am going through Rithm School coding exercises where I have encountered a snag with the testing of one of the questions, called findFirstMove.

From their website:

> Write a function called findFirstMove. This function accepts an array of arrays of moves and a move. It should return an array with the index of the first move in the array of arrays of moves. If the move is not present in the moves array, the function should return -1.

I'm still in the beginning and have not encountered any additional methods. I have only learnt till basic array methods, objects and basic functions. In array methods I have learnt only the starting ones like splice, slice, concat, join and some more I don't remember

It's a pretty simple question and this is the code that I had written:

```
function findFirstMove(moves, char) {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i=0; i<moves.length; i++)
    {
        for(let j=0; j<moves[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(moves[i][j] === char)
            {
                 newArr.push(i,j)
            }
        }
    }

    let test = []
    if(newArr.length)
    {
        test = newArr.splice(newArr.length - 2, 2)
        return newArr
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }
    
}
```

For the following test array:

```
let moves = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "a", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "h"],
  ];
```

This is the expected output:

```
  console.log(findFirstMove(moves, "a")); // [0, 0]
  console.log(findFirstMove(moves, "h")); // [2, 1]
```

Now with my local VS Code, in my chrome console, I'm getting the result, [0,0] for "a" and [2,1] for "h" but when I try running it against their test suite, it fails for these 2 cases. Here are their tests:

```
describe("findFirstMove", function () {
  it("should return the index of the first move in the array of arrays of moves", function () {
    const moves = [
      ["a", "b", "c"],
      ["d", "e", "f"],
      ["g", "h", "i"],
    ];
    const move = "a";
    const result = findFirstMove(moves, move);
    expect(result).toEqual([0, 0]);
  });
  it("should return the index of the first move in the array of arrays of moves", function () {
    const moves = [
      ["a", "b", "c"],
      ["d", "e", "f"],
      ["g", "h", "i"],
    ];
    const move = "h";
    const result = findFirstMove(moves, move);
    expect(result).toEqual([2, 1]);
  });
  it("should return the index of the first move in the array of arrays of moves", function () {
    const moves = [
      ["a", "b", "c"],
      ["d", "e", "f"],
      ["g", "h", "i"],
    ];
    const move = "z";
    const result = findFirstMove(moves, move);
    expect(result).toEqual(-1);
  });
});
```

Now the funny thing is when I change the line where I'm returning newArr to test, the test suite passes. But in my chrome console, the result of test is [1,1] for "a" and [2,2] for "h". Which is not the same as their test suite.

They are using Jasmine as their test framework.

I have tried asking chatGPT and it provided a solution that passes their test. This is the solution:

```
     function findFirstMove(moves, char) {
      let newArr = []
        for(let i=0; i<moves.length; i++)
        {
            for(let j=0; j<moves[i].length; j++)
            {
                if(moves[i][j] === char)
                {
                     return [i,j]
                }
            }
        }
            return -1
    }
```

This solution works but even its confused on why this is happening with code that I have written. I'm aware the code quality of mine is poor and I'm in the very beginning stages but I just want to understand what I'm doing wrong in my code since I'm able to pass it locally or if I'm misunderstanding the usage of splice(). The code given by chatGPT and also the commenters is the right way but this is for the sake of understanding. Thank you all so much for the responses.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to declare a `newArr` and modify it with `push` and  `splice` at all. Just `return [i, j]` when you found the move.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to invest a lot of effort into populating an array of all found matches and then stripping it down to a single match. However, the exercise only asks to find a first match, so instead of adding `i, j` to the matches array, you can simply stop the function right there and return the result

```
        if(moves[i][j] === char)
        {
            return [i, j]
        }
```

More on `return` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Hey, thank you for the wishes. Yes, this is the exact result chatGPT gave. But I wanted to solve it my way first before relying on it. In my initial prompts, I asked it to not give me the solution and only to poke holes in my understanding. But after failing the tests and trying to see what I have done wrong, even chatGPT is confused why this error is happening since it says my code is indeed correct. Its inefficient as you have pointed but it produces the result. Maybe its something very simple and I'm just not seeing it. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I 100% understand your question but basically what you're doing is this:

`newArr` stores **all** the coordinates where the move matches.
So for `"a"`, **before** calling `splice`, it looks this:
`newArr = [0,0,1,1]` where each pair of numbers represents a coordinate. Therefore `[0,0]` and `[1,1]`.
When you call `.splice()` you're removing 2 elements starting from the second last element; effectively removing the last two entries in `newArr`. This happens **in-place**, meaning that afterwards `newArr = [0,0]`. Not only that, but `splice()` returns the deleted elements. Meaning that `test = [1,1]`.

Since you only always want the first move, all you have to do is to return the first two numbers in `newArr` because that's always the first match.

In fact, you don't even have to finish the loops. You can just immediately return the result after calling `push(i,j)`. I took your code and added some print statements to illustrate what I've said with log outputs and a revised function. I hope this helps.

```js
function findFirstMove(moves, char) {
    let newArr = []
    for(let i=0; i<moves.length; i++)
    {
        for(let j=0; j<moves[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(moves[i][j] === char)
            {
                 newArr.push(i,j)
            }
        }
    }

    let test = []
    if(newArr.length)
    {
        console.log("before splice newArr = ", newArr.toString())
        test = newArr.splice(newArr.length - 2, 2);
        console.log("after splice newArr = ", newArr.toString())
        console.log("test = ", test.toString());
        return newArr
    }
    else
    {
        return -1
    }   
}

function findFirstMove2(moves, char) {
    for(let i=0; i<moves.length; i++)
    {
        for(let j=0; j<moves[i].length; j++)
        {
            if(moves[i][j] === char)
            {
                 return [i,j]
            }
        }
    }
    return -1
}


let moves = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["d", "a", "f"],
    ["g", "h", "h"],
  ];

console.log("result =  ", findFirstMove(moves, "a").toString());
console.log("result2 =  ", findFirstMove2(moves, "a").toString());
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. Yes, the idea I had was to take just the first 2 elements of all the elements of the newArr. Yours as well other commenter's methods are the right way since its efficient. Mine is very inefficient but my confusion stems from the fact that I am getting the desired result and its still failing the test despite the fact that the answers are the same. I'm getting the same result as is there in the test suite but its flagged as incorrect. Which is why I am thinking my understanding of splice() is still unclear.

Comment: @Kruseverve but you said yourself that the answers are not the same. For 'a' there are two matches: [0,0] and [1,1]. As I have explained, by using splice your `test` variable will contain the last two elements that have been removed from `newArr`.
The reason the testSuite passes when you use `test` is because there's no duplicate moves in the input argument `moves` (all the letters are different).
As such, before calling `splice()` the variable `newArr` will only ever have one match and thus contain only two numbers. After using `splice()` those elements are removed and put into `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [MDN documentation of splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), splice will remove elements of the original Array and return an Array with all the remove Elements.

In your case,

```
if(newArr.length)
{
    test = newArr.splice(newArr.length - 2, 2)
    return newArr
}
else
{
    return -1
}
```

You remove the last two elements from *newArray* and save the removed elements in *test*.

This explains the behavior of the tests.

```
let moves = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "a", "f"],
  ["g", "h", "h"]
];
console.log(findFirstMove(moves, "a")); // [0, 0]
```

In your test, since their are 2 occurrences, of the move "a", *newArray* will collect 4 Numbers, remove the last two of them and *findFirstMove* will return the right answer. But in their test :

```
const moves = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e", "f"],
  ["g", "h", "i"],
];
const move = "a";
const result = findFirstMove(moves, move);
```

*moves* contains only one "a". Therefore *newArray* will only collect 2 numbers, removes both of them and *findFirstMove* returns an empty Array.

There are multiple ways to solve this and I'm sure, that you can come up with a solution now.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. I tried solving it my way despite chatGPT's solution as I dont want to rely on it. But the weird thing is my code actually produces the result, no matter how inefficient it is, in my chrome console. It produces the output expected in the test suite, yet it fails in the test suite. Why is that? Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Kruseverve If I use the moves Array from their test suit, your code returns an empty Array in my chrome. Note that the test suits moves Array is different from your test Array.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and omit splicing which mutates the array.

If you really need to splice, take the new [`Array#toSpliced`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSpliced) to get a new Array without unwanted items.

```js
const
    find = (array, value) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] === value) return [i];
            if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
                const indices = find(array[i], value);
                if (indices) return [i, ...indices];
            }
        }
    },
    moves = [["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "a", "f"], ["g", "h", "h"]];

console.log(find(moves, 'a')); // [0, 0]
console.log(find(moves, 'h')); // [2, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm still trying to get comfortable with recursion and your solution is pretty advanced for me at the moment. When I'm more comfortable with it, I'll return and try solving all these problems with recursion and I'll take note of your process in solving this. Thank you for providing a recursive solution to the problem.